# Allow html/markdown to footer in VuePress

Tags: vue.js, markdown, yaml-front-matter, vuepress

I am trying to add html/markdown to the footer variable in VuePress default theme. I would like to add url in te footer that links to my website. However, I cannot find a way to add url to the footer. Can you please tell me how can i do that?
Here is my frontmatter:

```
—

home: true

footer: Developed by [John Doe ](http://mywebsite.com). || Powered by VuePress

---
```

How can i do that? According this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/859) in Github, this feature is still not available, however, there must be a workaround?

Answer (score 4):

**Without copying theme:**
You can use [vue components in markdown](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/using-vue.html#using-components).
Downside: `<Footer/>` has to be copied in every page/markdown file and your footer is inside `<main>`.

Create folder/file `.vuepress/components/Footer.vue`

```
<template>
  <footer>
<!-- html in here -->
  </footer>
</template>

<style lang="stylus" scoped>
// css/stylus here or in global stylus file
</script>
```

In your markdown add `<Footer/>` at bottom of every page.

**With theme copy:**
- create component `Footer.vue` as above
- console: `vuepress eject` [(docs here)](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/default-theme-config.html#ejecting)
- Go to `.vuepress\theme\Layout.vue`
- below `</Page>` add `<Footer/>`

Answer (score 1):

If the default theme does not provide that, you would need to build your own theme :-/

Maybe copy the [default theme](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/tree/master/packages/%40vuepress/theme-default) and put that into `.vuepress/theme`? I'd probably add a custom footer in the `Layout.vue` file ([here](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/blob/master/packages/%40vuepress/theme-default/layouts/Layout.vue#L46-L47)), also don't forget to put it into the `404.vue` file as well :)

There's also a markdown package shipped within Vuepress, so you might be able to use that to render the markdown string from frontmatter?

Sorry to not provide a "works out of the box" answer – seems like it's not that simple.